# Various questions about Flutter url_launcher and how to control the WebView behind it

Tags: url, webview, webkit, flutter

I am just starting to work with url_launcher in our Flutter application -- and it's going ok but the results are different than our native iOS/Android apps.

First, on iOS when I feed it a HTTP path to various types of doc types (image, PDF, etc.) we can issue a

self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

And this makes it look pretty nice actually.  I don't see a way to do that in Flutter ?

On my stock Android emulator -- all these file types (doc, xls, etc) just show up Blank .. if I use the built in WebKit thing

forceWebView:  true,

.. if I use the native browser it downloads the file and in the Download area .. if I click on the file it says "Can't open" ..  Is there a way to get the same results on iOS (basically a Preview?) in Android?

Also I would like to scale the page to fit on Android too -- and -- if the image is too big -- it doesn't let one scroll around to see the whole thing..

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental here?  But there aren't a lot of options in the launcher to mess up.  :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) will do just that: "launch a URL", and it's up to your phone configuration how that is handled. But key issue is: It's in most cases a *external* App.

You are probably looking for a plugin like [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) or [flutter_web_browser](https://github.com/victorbonnet/flutter_web_browser).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian -- but actually the code for url_launcher creates a WebKit for Android (with an option) and by default uses an internal webview for iOS .. just like my native iOS code .. the difference is that I can find a way to control the creation  / options using url_launcher ... I was hoping not to have to hand roll the same code as url_launcher (for all practical purposes) ... On the other hand your pointers to the lower level libraries is very helpful!  Thanks!